# Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax: Update does not trasmit the data in the db because of this error

Tags: php, mysql

In the error it tells that the error is near

```
'UPDATE 'item' SET price='120' WHERE itemName ='Cebu - Manila Airpla' at line `2`
```

Here is my php code that adds the entry to the database

```
$updateEntry1 ="SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
                    UPDATE 'item' 
                    SET price='120'
                    WHERE itemName ='Cebu - Manila Airplane Ticket';";

    retrieveTable($updateEntry1);
```

Here is the retrieve table function which is a function that stores the info in the db

```
function retrieveTable($query){
$config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini'); 
$connect = mysqli_connect($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)or die (mysqli_error($connect)); 
return $filter_Result;}
```

Comment: You have single quotes around `'item'`.  I consider this a typographical error and vote to close.  *Only* use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three aspect
firts be sure that you can use two sql statemnts  in a single query with  your sql  driver

```
$updateEntry1 ="SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

second...  price should be a number and not a string

and third tablename without quote

```
                UPDATE  item
                SET price=120
                WHERE itemName ='Cebu - Manila Airplane Ticket';";
```

Comment: Yup! the single quote did it

Comment: @MarcoM.   well .. i don't know your table schema and you sql drvire so i have  posted  a list of critical  issue and error ..